# Cookie migration when changing domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

Recently I'm moving my website to a new domain, and I want to migrate user cookies to the new domain too, so they don't have to log in again.

After some research, I found there are two potential ways to do it:

1. Land user first on old-domain.com, update all cookies with new-domain.com so they can be accessed from new-domain.com, then do a browser redirect to new-domain.com;
2. Alternatively, on the new-domain.com, I can inject an iframe from old-domain.com, to let it write cookies to the new website...

I'm not sure if these two can achieve my goal to migrate cookies between domains. Is there a suggestied ways to do it, so that user doesn't have to sign in again to use the new domain?

Comment: #1 won't work, you can't set a cookie for a different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like #2 can work.

On the new page, check if the cookies are already set. If not, inject an iframe like:

```
<iframe src="http://old-domain.com/getcookies.html" style="height: 0; width: 0;">
```

`getcookies.html` will just contain Javascript that gets the cookies and uses [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send them to the new page. Javascript on the new page will receive the message and then set the cookies that it receives.

There are some potential issues with this:

1. Loading the iframe and having it send the cookies is asynchronous. What should the page do while it's waiting?
2. If you use cookies on the server, the above code doesn't set them until the client receives the page from the server. The server will need to deal with non-migrated users specially, by first sending them the script that copies the cookies, and it then redirects them back to the server script.
3. You have to deal with users that were never on the old domain. `getcookies.html` should detect that none of the cookies are set, and send back a message indicating this.

I suggest you add a new cookie `migrated=yes` that can be used to detect whether the user needs to go through any of this.

Comment: I think you mean `postMessage()`, not `sendMessage()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thanks. Corrected it and added the link to the answer.